Libreoffice WebDAV over SSL to Nextcloud Fails
RELEVANT CONFIG'N

libreoffice 7.3.7.2 and Firefox 126.0.2 (snap) on UbuntuStudio 22.04.08 (snap) on desktop PC.
Nextcloud (27.1.9snap1) on Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 LTS (snap) configured to use SSL
Network is an Ethernet home LAN.
I installed and used Wireshark running on Desktop PC.

PROBLEM:  I cannot get Libreoffice to open and save documents on my Nextcloud server.  More specifically, the Libreoffice dialogue fails to negotiate a valid remote service. The LibreOffice error message reads:
Could not establish Internet connection to server.home.arpa.
DIAGNOSIS  I wasted many hours checking firewalls, nextcloud settings, looking for nextcloud's Apache setup inside the nextcloud snap and on the desktop PC.  Snaps do not make diagnosis easy.
Why LibreOffice and not other WebDAV capable programs?  Firefox was the only other application I have that speaks WebDAV.  If I put the WebDAV URL into Firefox address bar it saves the file where Firefox saves downloads.  Very fast!
https://server.home.arpa/remote.php/dav/files/emma/any-document.ext

I eventually installed and used WireShark on my desktop PC to inspect the LAN traffic (i.e. TCP & SSL frames).  LibreOffice sends (TCP) RESET messages when using the Open Remote and Save Remote functions, the bit where one sets up a remote service.  These RESET messages happen after message frames negotiate which TLS protocol to use successfully.

LibreOffice sends a request to Nextcloud.
Nextcloud sends a reply in a sequence of frames, each of which are
properly acknowledged.
LibreOffice then sends one or two RESET messages to the server
LibreOffice displays an error dialog box as mentioned.

This looks like a software bug in LibreOffice.  I don't think I can make any headway with this.  Can anyone reading this answer these questions?
QUESTIONS

Does this problem exists for other users?
Is there a known workaround?
Has LibreOffice fixed the problem in a downstream version?
Does LibreOffice know about this problem (Bugzilla/JIRA)?

Any answers would be appreciated.  Thank you.

There is a possibility that Ask LibreOffice might have someone who can answer your question

I've just tested with Linux Mint 21.3 (LO 7.3.7.2) and Nextcloud 28.05 with SSL using a LetsEncrypt certificate. Didn't encounter any problems. So just guessing - are you using a self-signed certificate/did you try without SSL (use a SSH tunnel)? Do the Nextcloud logs show anything? Could you provide a screenshot of your WebDAV settings in LibreOffice (with server name blurred)? Do you use 2FA for the NextCloud login?

That's helpful. The server is headless. I'm using a self signed certificate. I have created a Root CA, an Intermediate CA signed by the Root CA and create keys for all servers on my network.  The Root and Intermediate CA public keys are loaded on the servers and clients /etc/ssl/certs.  One thing I did notice was the the server was being given a FQDN by the ISP's router "server name.lan" My SSL certificate does not mention "server name.lan" I need to find a way to check that LibreOffice is not reacting badly to a potential warning the certificate doesn't authorise that particular FQDN.

I will dig around to find NC logs. I'm going look for an SSL tester.  I will try disabling SSL, but that generates security warnings in Firefox. I haven't set up 2FA (yet), I might not need it as this is used within the LAN and not pass through the firewall.

More digging (using delv and googling) uncovered some SSL problems, which I have now rectified.  I have also successfully used my Nextcloud WebDAV over SSL from my smartphone: very easy.  I think I am about ready to take graham's suggestion and then maybe raise raise a LibreOffice support case/ticket. Wireshark traffic analysis hints at LibreOffice having a problem with TLSv1.3 SSL messages carrying TLSv1.2 content when setting up Remote Open using WebDAV .  I was not able to convince myself I could disable HTTPS without making a mess, so I cannot really be certain.
